# Entity Framework Is it possible to add an ASSOCIATION between Primary Keys and a Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-4, associations

I've got the following entities on my EDMX :-
[image]

These two entites were generated by *Update Model From Database*.

Now, notice how my country has the following primary key :-

**Name** & **IsoCode**

this is because each country is UNIQUE in the system by Name and IsoCode.

Now, with my States ... it's similar. Primary Key is :-

**Name** & **CountryId**

Each state is unique by name and per country.

Now, the Foreign Key for States is a CountryId. This is the sql :-

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[States]  WITH CHECK ADD 
        CONSTRAINT [FK_States_Countries] FOREIGN KEY([CountryId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Countries] ([CountryId])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[States] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_States_Countries]
GO
```

Pretty simple stuff.

BUT EntityFramework doesn't like it :( It's assuming that i need to connect some properties from `State` entity to both primary key properties in the `Country` entity.

**Is it possible to add an ASSOCIATION between Country and State on Country.CountryId <-> State.CountryId ... like i have mapped in my DB ?**

Cheers ;)

Comment: @Alex James : are you around to help, kind sir?

Comment: Yeap... see the answer below!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In EF (3.5 and 4.0) FKs MUST point to Primary Keys.

But you appear to be attempting to point to a Candidate Key (i.e. [Countries].[CountryId]

I know that this is something the EF team are considering for the next version though :)

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Thank you kindly Alex for picking up on my question. I sincerly appreciate it :) Looks like i'll go back to making the identities the PK's and adding unique constraints. Doh :) always one step ahead of the current EF builds... :) Thanks again mate - really love your help :) keep it up!

Comment: I looked at the CTP5 change docs and didn't see anything related to this. Is this feature still being considered, or in the pipeline, or...? This is a real stumbling block for mapping legacy databases.

Answer (score 0):

For proper DB normalization, first thing is that primary keys must be only **CountryId** and **StateId** fields - the main Id fields for each table.

And ss I see from the description **Name & IsoCode**  and  **Name & CountryId**  should be actually *Unique keys*, not primary.

Then the model class **State** should have a field:

```
public Country Country { get; set; }
```

Now EF have very good examples and since 4.3.1 + it fully supports Code first / DB first models, which I think will ease solving this.
EF 5 have more compatibility updates so I think it wont be a problem for legacy DB engines.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood your answer somehow - this is completely beside the point of the question.

"Is it possible to add an ASSOCIATION between Country and State on Country.CountryId <-> State.CountryId" is the question - as in "Can I add an association on something other than a primary key (the candidate key in this case)"