# Entity Framework: Alternate solution to using non primary unique keys in an association

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I know the entity frame work does not allow you to generate a model from a database using non primary unique keys as a Foreign Key association.  Can I modify the EDMX manually? If so, can someone provide me an example or reference?  If not, are there any other possibilities?

**Easiest Example:**

Here is the DDL for the tables.  You will notice I have a foreign Key from PersonType.TypeCode to Person.TypeCode

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonType](
    [PersonTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TypeDesc] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PersonType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 ([PersonTypeId] ASC)
 CONSTRAINT [UK_PersonType] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
 ([TypeCode] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TypeCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 ([PersonId] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_PersonType] FOREIGN KEY([TypeCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PersonType] ([TypeCode])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Person_PersonType]
```

**Here is the EDMX Generated**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="testModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="testModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="Person" EntityType="testModel.Store.Person" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          <EntitySet Name="PersonType" EntityType="testModel.Store.PersonType" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Person">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="PersonId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="PersonId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="TypeCode" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" />
        </EntityType>
        <!--Errors Found During Generation:
      warning 6035: The relationship 'FK_Person_PersonType' has columns that are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the relationship. The relationship was excluded.
      -->
        <EntityType Name="PersonType">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="PersonTypeId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="PersonTypeId" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="TypeCode" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" />
          <Property Name="TypeDesc" Type="varchar(max)" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="testModel" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="testEntities">
          <EntitySet Name="People" EntityType="testModel.Person" />
          <EntitySet Name="PersonTypes" EntityType="testModel.PersonType" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Person">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="PersonId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="PersonId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="TypeCode" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="PersonType">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="PersonTypeId" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="PersonTypeId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="TypeCode" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="TypeDesc" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows:storage:mapping:CS">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="testModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="testEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="People"><EntityTypeMapping TypeName="testModel.Person"><MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Person">
            <ScalarProperty Name="PersonId" ColumnName="PersonId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="TypeCode" ColumnName="TypeCode" />
          </MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping></EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="PersonTypes"><EntityTypeMapping TypeName="testModel.PersonType"><MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="PersonType">
            <ScalarProperty Name="PersonTypeId" ColumnName="PersonTypeId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="TypeCode" ColumnName="TypeCode" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="TypeDesc" ColumnName="TypeDesc" />
          </MappingFragment></EntityTypeMapping></EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
```

I have tried to modify the EDMX to create the navigation propery between personType and Person but have been unsuccessful.  I just figured I could create the association manually some how.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand your schema. This looks like a `1-1` right? A `Person` has a particular `PersonType`. What i don't understand is why the `PersonType` table has a field called `PersonTypeId`. If this is a lookup table, shouldn't you just have `TypeCode` (PK), and `TypeDesc`? And then the FK on `Person` to `TypeCode` would work fine, as it's a PK.

Comment: @RPM1984 ..The example is just a simple example.  Its not something im using but something to show the problem.  Basically the EF will not allow you to generate a model using non-primary Unique Keys.

Comment: Ok - but i think EF is doing the right thing here. Even though the field is `unique`, a FK should reference a PK, not a UK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately as of now there is no way to define an association on a candidate key (i.e. *PersonType.TypeCode*). because **In EF (3.5 and 4.0) FKs MUST point to Primary Keys.**

According to [*Alex James*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/) from [*his post here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714334/entity-framework-is-it-possible-to-add-an-association-between-primary-keys-and-a), this is something the EF team are considering for the next version.

Comment: Four years later, still not supported ((

Comment: Seriously, how can people use such "enterprise" tripe. The abandoned LinqToSQL (which is/was a much better ORM *start*) and EF1 did better. EF 6.1 - even though such was promised - still seems to lack such a *basic* RA principle.

Comment: EF 6.1.2 (2015/02) still not supported :(

Comment: EF 6.2 Still not supported

Comment: Any way to get around this?

Comment: still not supported

Comment: still not suppoted

Comment: still not supported

Comment: EF 6.4.4 still not supported.