# How to prevent duplicate records in a mapping table in MVC3?

Tags: duplicates, record, rdbms

I have the following tables:

```
Client (PKey = ClientId)
User   (PKey = UserId) 

UserClient (FKeys = ClientId, UserId)
```

When I try to add a record (mapping) in the UserClient table such that User-Client pair should be unique, it allows duplicate records.

I want to prevent that. Meaning, when trying to add existing User-Client pair then it should throw client side validation.

How can i prevent entry of duplicate record in a mapping table in MVC3?

Comment: Did you make the ClientId & UserId in UserClient the Primary Key not just a foreign key?

Comment: Yes, I have a primary key UserClientId in UserClient table.

Comment: This isn't an issue with MVC3.  It's a database design issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to uniquly identify columns.
Yu can achieve this with help of Candidate Key in SQL server, But it not supported in entity framework.

[Entity Framework: Alternate solution to using non primary unique keys in an association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992236/entity-framework-alternate-solution-to-using-non-primary-unique-keys-in-an-asso)

Answer (score 0):

You'll get duplicates since UserClientId is independent of the foreign key you setup. Foreign keys only ensure that the keys being inserted into the UserClient table exists in the User and Client tables.

If possible remove the UserClientId primary key and set your ClientId & UserId as the primary key also for the UserClient table. You then will have duplicates handled and foreign key integrity.

Here's what the Entity Relationship Diagram would look like:

[image]