# Problem in mapping fragments in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following model:

[image]

But when i compile with VS2010, i get the following error:

Error 2 Error 3007: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 1784, 2018:Column(s) [createdby] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties.

What do i want ? Actually i want the Note entity to have FK to User entity.
When does the error appear ? When i add the FK User to Note i have the error. If i remove the link, no problem.
What is the problem ?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 2):

I also have a "User" entity (based on a View) and several tables with CreatedByUser and ModifiedByUser references.

This works for me without getting the "must be null" error:

- On the "Note" entity: right-click:  “Add > Association...”.
- Select "User" as the  right-side "End Entity".
- Swap the multiplicities:  "Notes" should be "Many" and "User" should be "One".
- I deselect the right-side Navigation  Property, as I'll never navigate from "User" to the other tables:  but that's up to you.
- If you have both "CreatedBy" and "ModifiedBy" properties, then you might want to change the Association Name to  something more meaningful (e.g.   change "NoteUser" to  "NoteCreatedByUser"
- Ditto for the Navigation   Property (e.g.  change "User" to "CreatedByUser")
- Leave “Add foreign key   properties....” unchecked.
- Click OK.
- IMPORTANT:  in the “Properties”   window, go to Referential Constraint   and click the ellipsis.
- Select "User" as the Principal.
- Change the Dependent Property to the   appropriate value (e.g.   "CreatedBy")
- Click OK.

Done!

Screen shots from my project below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the association on the User entity has been defined on *Username* and Username is a candidate key (has a unique index defined on it) in SQL Server. While you can create a relationship based on this setup in SQL Server, current version of EF does *NOT* support creating associations based on candidate keys: ***[In EF (3.5 and 4.0) FKs MUST point to Primary Keys.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714334/having-serious-problems-with-entity-framework-foreign-keys/3714831#3714831)***

The only way to make this working is to create a new int field inside *Note* table (like *UserId*) and then create a new relationship between *User.Id* (PK) and *Note.UserID* (FK) and EF will happily create a association based on that for you.

Comment: I update the answer to be more specific. Please check it out.

Comment: Sorry, there is something unclear...if i do that : how will this change from my "createdby" current field ?

Comment: ok i did add the field and it works, but should i feed it with the same values like 'created by', i need to change my app so it feeds it ?

Comment: I would say just get rid of it, with having a *UserId* as FK in Note table, the *createdby* is redundant. From now on, each time you query *Notes*, you can also Eager Load *User* navigation property and access its *Username* to learn about *createdby*. Lazy Loading will do that for you as well.

Comment: Hi i have implemented what you said and it indeed works BUT when i save it i have the following error:The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.